# Sum distinct in SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Let's say there's an `order` and `order_line` table. To calculate the revenue for each customer, I use the following query -

```
select o.customer_id, sum(o.amount) as revenue
from order o join order_line ol on o.id=ol.order_id
where ol.coupon_code is NULL
group by 1
```

Let's assume that `coupon_code` is only available at the order line level, hence we need to join to `order_line`. If an order can have multiple line items, the sum of revenue will be double-counted due to the join.

Want to know if there's a way to calculate the sum of `amount` for distinct orders only. This seems like such a common use case that there's likely an easy solution for it, but I can't think of it.

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images. And don't forget to have different coupon_code statuses.

Comment: Will all ol.coupon_code values be the same for an order?

Comment: Are you trying to exclude orders that contain 1/more coupon_codes?

Answer (score 0):

use subquery

```
select o.customer_id, sum(o.amount) as revenue
from "order" o join 
( select  distinct coupon_code,order_id from order_line
) ol on o.id=ol.order_id
where ol.coupon_code is NULL
group by o.customer_id
```